# Migrating from SalesForce to Dynamics using SSIS

Tags: ssis, salesforce, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to migrate my company's data from SalesForce to Dynamics, using SSIS. This has been attempted by others in the past using Scribe, and has apparently been unsuccessful, because there were fields we wanted to enter which Dynamics wouldn't let us because they were system generated (such as Created Date.) Nobody at my company is exactly sure how to go about using SSIS to migrate from SalesForce to Dynamics...they just know that they want it done that way and they do not think any third party tool will be helpful. I'm having an extremely hard time finding ANYTHING online that isn't an advertisement for a third party tool. Does anyone know of some kind of guide or tutorial, or really any information at all on using SSIS to do this kind of migration?

Answer (score 1):

The consulting firm that I work for has successfully used Scribe to migrate from SalesForce to CRM.  Had some hoops to jump through, but it worked.

And as far as the created date goes, there is the [override date field](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mileyja/archive/2012/11/12/overriding-the-createdon-attribute-on-entities-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx#.Ui3mNsZnFrg) to use.  I guess you could use SSIS, I'm just not sure it's going to be any easier.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Kingsway Soft's SSIS Toolkit with a lot of success in the past. They have a free trial available here along with documentation for how to use the toolkit in SSIS.

http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm

They support both Dynamics CRM and Salesforce so you should be able to pull from salesforce, transform the data if necessary and push to Dynamics CRM.

You can use this along with Daryl's suggestion for overriddencreatedon and migrate data across pretty simply.

Answer (score 0):

I have used talend in the past to migrate from other CRM systems in to salesforce. Not sure if this will help you in doing the vice versa. 
It's a powerful tool and you can perhaps check it out. Use the opensource version.

Answer (score 0):

Before you select the technology... do you have a full mapping of all source tables/fields to target tables/fields? without this you can't do anything. That's why you normally engage an external consultant, because they know all this stuff already.

The issue isn't the tool, it's the mapping. If you don't know what goes into those fields, a tool isn't going to help unless it has some product specific controls that generate those values for you.